# Formset in Django Classbased CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Model

```py
class Timetable(models.Model):
    day = models.CharField(max_length=9,choices=timetable_choices)
    start = models.IntegerField()
    end = models.IntegerField()
    period = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

Views

```py
class Timetableadding(CreateView):
    model =  Timetable
    fields = ['day','period','start' ,'end']
    success_url = '/dashboard'
```

What I need is to process a view similar to following image ,
[image]

NB: I am not good in js so i want a solution without the use of JS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Views

```py
class Timetableadding(CreateView):
    model =  Timetable
    success_url = '/dashboard/'
    form_class = Timetableform
    template_name = 'form.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Timetableadding, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = TimetableFormSet(queryset=Timetable.objects.none())
        context['day_form'] = DayForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = TimetableFormSet(request.POST)
        day_form = DayForm(data=request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid() and day_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset,day_form)

    def form_valid(self, formset,day_form):
        day = day_form.cleaned_data['day']
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.day = day
            instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
```

#### Forms

```py
class DayForm(Form):
    day = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Day.objects.all())


class Timetableform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Timetable
        fields = ( 'day','start', 'end', 'period')

TimetableFormSet = modelformset_factory(Timetable, fields=('start', 'end', 'period'),extra=8,)
```

#### Template

```py
{% csrf_token %}
{{ day_form }} <br>
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
{{ form }}<br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But how do you handle error in your inline forms with this solution?

Comment: if formset is not valid, post function returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

### CREATE FORMS.PY

```py
class MyForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Timetable
        fields = ['day','start','end','period',]
```

### Views.py

```py
from django.forms import formset_factory  
class YourView(CreateView):
    form = formset_factory(MyForm)
    model = Timetable
    success_url ="Your success url"
    template_name = "your template"
```

## In  Your Templates

```html
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">             
                {{ form.management_form }}                                          
                {% for contact in form %}
                <div class="link-formset">
                    {{ contact.as_p }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <button class="user-sent" type="submit" value="Send"> Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </fieldset>
    <script src="{% static 'forms/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script> 
    <script>
        $('.link-formset').formset({
            addText: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add User',
            deleteText: '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Remove'
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: The answer doesn't work . I cant understand  . it would be better if you post the answer in a more comfortable way with some explanation

Comment: tell me what exactly you wanna achieve. using formset.

Comment: kindly share   screenshot with me what output your getting.

Comment: as i said in the question and shown in the screenshot , I want the user to add the day only once and the rest of the fields to be added 8 times . I saw similar one using functional view . Is there any possibility using CBV . 
The template you provided just render a send button nothing else

Comment: share the functional view.