# Return many forms in one view - Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm not advanced in Django yet, so please be understanding. I'm currently working on creating my portfolio app. The idea is to build something similar to https://track.toggl.com. I frequently use this tool, and I thought that replicating this project could be an interesting challenge and a valuable addition to my CV as a beginner programmer.

In the Home View, I aim to return a couple of forms:

- One blank form for creating a new Time Entry record in the project.
- Multiple forms pre-filled with data from the database.

In the template of the Home View, I intend to display a list of all pre-filled forms to the user. This way, users can edit the data according to their preferences without the need for separate views/templates for editing.

Now, my question is as follows: is the solution I've prepared suitable?
**Of course the most important is logic behind `create_forms_for_user_data` method, and is it properly used in `get` method.**

```
views.py 
class HomeView(view):
    template_name = 'pages/home.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Should return :
        - User's all time entries
        - A form to create a new time entry
        - A list of forms to edit time entries
        """
        user_data = self.get_user_data()
        blank_form = CombinedForm()
        filled_forms = self.create_forms_for_user_data()


        context = {
            'form': blank_form,
            'user_data': user_data,
            'filled_forms': filled_forms,
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CombinedForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            task_name, task_project, start_time, end_time = form.save()

            task_object = Task.objects.get(name=task_name)
            project_object = Project.objects.get(name=task_project)

            time_entry = TimeEntry(
                user=request.user,
                task_id=task_object,
                project_id=project_object,
                start_time=start_time,
                end_time=end_time,
            )
            time_entry.save()

        user_data = self.get_user_data()
        context = {'form': form, 'user_data': user_data}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def get_user_data(self):
        """
        Testing puposes, currently not used
        Returns a dictionary of the user's time entries in the following format:
        {
            'task_name': {
                'time_entry_id': {
                    'project': 'project_name',
                    'start_time': 'start_time',
                    'end_time': 'end_time',
                }
            }
        }
        :return:  dict
        """
        time_entries = TimeEntry.objects.order_by('-created_at').filter(user=self.request.user)
        result_dict = {}

        for time_entry in time_entries:
            if time_entry.task_id.name not in result_dict:
                task_name = time_entry.task_id.name
                if task_name not in result_dict:
                    result_dict[task_name] = {}

                result_dict[task_name][time_entry.id] = {
                    'project': time_entry.project_id.name,
                    'start_time': time_entry.start_time,
                    'end_time': time_entry.end_time if time_entry.end_time else None,
                }
        return result_dict

    def create_forms_for_user_data(self):
        """
        Creates a list of forms for the user's time entries where the end time is not null
        :return: list
        """
        time_entries = TimeEntry.objects.order_by('-created_at').filter(user=self.request.user).exclude(end_time=None) #Should return all time entries that have an end time
        forms = []
        for time_entry in time_entries:
            data = { 'task_name': time_entry.task.name,
                     'task_project': time_entry.project.name,
                     'start_time': time_entry.start_time,
                     'end_time': time_entry.end_time,}
            form = CombinedForm(data)
            forms.append(form)
        return forms
```

```
forms.py 
class CombinedForm(forms.Form):
    task_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Task Name')
    task_project = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.all(), required=False, label='Task Project')

    start_time = forms.DateTimeField(label='Time Entry Start Time', widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}))
    end_time = forms.DateTimeField(label='Time Entry End Time', widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}))

    def save(self):
        task_name = self.cleaned_data['task_name']
        task_project = self.cleaned_data['task_project']

        start_time = self.cleaned_data['start_time']
        end_time = self.cleaned_data['end_time']

        return task_name, task_project, start_time, end_time
```

```
models.py
class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # TODO : add a field for the project's color
    # Potencial todos : start_date, end_date, duration, is_archived, is_deleted
    # color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="#000000")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tasks')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class TimeEntry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='time_entries')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    duration = models.DurationField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.start_time and self.end_time:
            self.duration = self.end_time - self.start_time
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.project.name} - {self.start_time} to {self.end_time}"
```

I understand that using frontend frameworks might make solving this type of problem easier, but my knowledge of JavaScript is at a basic level.

From the template view it should contain the code similar to that :

```
{% block content %}
   <!-- Display blank_form -->
  <form method="post" action="{% url '#' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ blank_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <!-- Display filled_forms -->
  {% for filled_form in filled_forms %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'your_form_action_url' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ filled_form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you checked out django's formset factories which handles cases like these? Check out this answer, which shows how you can use a formset_factory to create such a scenario in class-based views: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087609/formset-in-django-classbased-createview